# webpack SSR load bundle with contenthash

Tags: webpack, server-side-rendering

How do you load a webpack compiled bundle with content hashed filenames when the html is generated by a backend?

There are plugins like `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, but they only work if you serve your SPA with a static `index.html` file .. If you want to SSR your application, there are 2 ways to go ...

somehow read the `manifest.json` from your static folder, ie `/assets/manifest.json` and inject the url in to your generated html... but then the question becomes .. how do you write that in your `./src` without linting issues (tslint), so that it works in both devServer and production builds?

add a script that downloads the `manifest.json` file to the users browser, gets the filename of the `main.[contenthash].js` or `bundle.[contenthash].js`, and then downloads that file and somehow executes it...